# antivirus keeps preventing me from compiling code

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Just wondereing, what kind of programming mistake in c++  would cause an antivirus to think the exe file compiled is a virus? It seems to happen when I play with pointers. Am I really creating something harmful to my computer, or is it just the antivirus giving a false positive and safe to ignore?

main

```
#include "node.h"
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    Node a(5);
    Node b(3);
    Node c(2);
    addSuccessor(&a,&b);
    addSuccessor(&a,&c);

    _getch();
return 0;
 }
```

node.h

```
 #include <ostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 using namespace std;
 class Node{
     public:
         Node();
         Node(short s);
         ~Node();
         void setValue(short s);
         short getValue();
         vector<Node*> getSuccessors();
         friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &os, Node &n);
     private:
         short value;
         vector<Node*> successors;
 };
 void addSuccessor(Node* initial, Node* successor)
```

node.cpp

```
#include "node.h"
#include <string>

Node:: Node(){
    value = 0;
}
Node::~Node(){
}
Node:: Node(short s){
    value = s; 
}
void Node::setValue(short n){
    value = n;
}
short Node::getValue(){
    return value;
}
vector<Node*> Node::getSuccessors(){
    return successors;
}

void addSuccessor(Node* initial, Node* successor){
    initial->getSuccessors().push_back(successor);
}


ostream & operator <<(ostream &os, Node &n){
    os << "N:"<< n.getValue() << "\n";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: What code are you compiling? I've had false positives quite a few times before, and not much when making things that could actually be used as a virus. Go figure.

Comment: Any chance you are assigning function pointers around? Code that modifies code segments could trigger antivirus.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista: or more likely access-violate (segfault).

Comment: What anti-virus are you using and what warning is it giving?

Comment: BitDefender, it says the virus is called Gen:Variant,Symmi.3652

Comment: Best one I had was when my AV quarantined visual studio for attaching to a process.

Comment: On a side note, your code has one small flaw. `Node::getSuccessors()` returns a copy of the vector of successors which means that your `addSuccessor(...)` function operates on the copy of the vector rather than adding to the original. I'm not sure if the antivirus would be complaining about this though. It could but it's unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. How would you suggest  i provide access to it? All i can think of is making it public.

Comment: Quite a few AV programs seem to assume that if anything except a recognized installation program tries to write a `.exe` file, it must be a virus -- what's in the code/what it does seems to be ignored entirely.

Comment: Try adding more code to your program. Symmi is apparently a trojan horse, so I'm guessing you might have just managed to make an executable with the same hash as it. (Or someone has infected your machine and the virus is infecting all your compiles!)